# Subclass to only replace constructor vs function that generates an instance

Tags: oop

Given a class A and a group of instances B that are created in the same way but have no extra functionallity to the class.

What would be the better pattern
subclassing A overriding only the constructor
or have a function that creates instances of group B

e.g.

```
class A
{
   int x;
   int y;
}
```

option A:

```
class B
{
constructor()
{
 super(0,random())
}
}
```

option B:

```
createB()
{
return new A(0,random())
}
```

EDIT:
class B constructor should've been using super

Answer (score 1):

The better approach is definitely not to create additional functions.
Constructors are meant for that and you should not move the logic away.

Rethink if you really need **B** class. Because if you don't, the whole code can be simplified to:

```
class A {
    int x;
    int y;
    
    public A() {
        x = 0;
        y = Math.random();
    }
    
    public A(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

In most of the languages, constructors can be overloaded based on the number and types of parameters.

If you really need **B** class, I suggest simply calling `super` constructor:

```
class A {
    int x;
    int y;
    
    public A(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    
    public B() {
        super(0, Math.random());
    }
}
```

I am not sure what do you mean by "instances were created in the same way", but with OOP you can instantiate parent class with an instance of a child, e.g.:

```
A a = new A(10,20);
A b = new B();
```

Comment: yeah definetly using super i will edit. in my case there's actually a class C with different functionallity ( new fild and method ) hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

**It's better to use option B.**

This is a classic pattern, named *Fabric Method* in fundamental book *Gang of Four*.

Comment: you mean factory? so if I have multiple groups e.g. C { contsrtuctor(){super(1,random())}}, it will mean a new function for each group. the thing is that with the class you may differentiate between A and B in an external overloaded function.